# last entry in home page

Tags: views, 7

I created a content type and created various entries. Each entry has the following fields:
name, photo, date.

How can I put a box on the home page with fields covering only the last entry?
(I would also like a page with squares side by side, sorted by date.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS [last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) selector to theme last entry as a box ! You need to write css in you active theme style.css.

> I would also like a page with squares side by side, sorted by date.

For above you need to use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module and display nodes in grid format sorted by sort filter date.